# Reload the page/form for refreshing the data when clicking the button

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, refresh, reload

How to reload the page or form in PHP.

The scenario: I have two forms with the same design/gui. I named it main.php and process.php.
Both page also have dropdownlist, same items. The items in the dropdownlist are "Net 1" and "Net 2" and under of "Net 1" is "Bldg 1" and for "Net 2" is "Bldg 2". So in the main.php when I click the submit it will proceed to the process.php. Then process.php will display the under item of the item I choose in the dropdownlist in main.php.

My problem is:
When the user want to see the under item of "Net 2". I want is, in the page of button_process.php will just reload or refresh the data so that the user will see the items for "Net 2", what should I do?

Code for main.php:

```
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
 Advertisement Name: <input type="text" name="adName" size="50"><br/><br/>
 Duration: <select id="duration"name="duration">
     <option value="5 s" >5 s</option>
         <option value="10 s" >10 s</option>
    <option value="15 s" >15 s</option>
    <option value="20 s" >20 s</option>
    <option value="30 s" >30 s</option>
    <option value="60 s" >60 s</option>
    </select><br/><br/>
    <b>Period</b>  <br/>
     From: <input type="text" id="datepickerfrom"name="from"> To: <input type="text" id="datepickerto"name="to">

    <span id="span_select">
        <select name="id">
            <option value="" >- select -</option>

            <?php
                include 'connect.php';

                $q = mysql_query("select fldNetname from tblnetwork");

                while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q))
                {
                  echo "<option value='".$row1[fldNetname]."'>".$row1[fldNetname]."</option>";

                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" name="pass" value="View Building/s">   
    </form>
Here's my Code for
```

process.php:
EDIT:

```
<form action="button_process.php" method="post">
echo "<div><input type='checkbox' class='checkall'> Check all</div>";
    $all = mysql_query("SELECT fldBldgName FROM tblbuildings");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($all))
       {

       echo "<div><input type='checkbox' name='play[]' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldBldgName']."'>";
       echo $row['fldBldgName'];"</div>";

       }


<input type="submit" name="pass" value="View Building/s">   
</form>
```

Code for button_process.php

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

switch ($_POST['pass']) {
      case 'View':
           //here I want to reload the page.
            break;


      case 'Save':
            echo "Add";
            break;
}

?>
```

Comment: why are you doing a form submit to just show a menu item?

Comment: @Patrick Evans, first I'm passing it to the next page just to load the under items. Second, I don't know how to load it in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

If reloading the page requires a user action, you will not be able to use PHP to reload the page, in this case, you would have to use Javascript.

If you want to reload a page using PHP, which will happen as the page load and before any html code is outputted, you can use this :

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

If you want to refresh the page after the user has executed an action, you will need a javascript event method on an element (for exemple, onclick() on a button), and within the method you can use the following code :

```
window.location.reload();
```

If this isn't sufficient to answer your question, please provide more details as to what you want to do. There is a better way to do it than what you are doing, with more details we might be able to help you more.

Comment: actually this is my problem since then. How can i view the items in grid when the user change something in the dropdown. The grid is for showing the items it depends to the dropdown.

Comment: You will have to use Javascript for that, I suggest you read a tutorial about Javascript, specifically "DOM Manipulation".

Comment: No, this is too specific and there is too little information about your case. You would need to show the entire HTML code if you want someone to help you more than that.

Comment: @Dany...I edit it again...thats all my html in main.php..main.php and process.php have just the same codes/gui.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty example of setting expanding menus on different pages. Build the menu items first then use a php script to set the parent menu item to have a `active` css style and have your css styles give the proper hide/show styles.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menuitem <?php echo $Page=="Net 1" ? "active" : "";?>">
        <span>Net 1</span>
        <div class="submenu">
            <div class="submenuitem">
                <span>Bldg 1</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div> class="menuitem <?php echo $Page=="Net 2" ? "active" : "";?>">
        <span>Net 2</span>
        <div class="submenu">
            <div class="submenuitem">
                <span>Bldg 2</span>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menuitem .submenu {
    display:none;
}

.menuitem.active .submenu {
    display:block;
}
```

where `$Page` is some php variable that holds the name of your menu item or however you want to tell your script which menu item the user is on.

Comment: hi... Uhm...the "net 2" and under of that "net 2" are came from database.